# Expo CLI requires installation after being installed (macOs)

Tags: macos, npm, expo

I am trying to run `-npm start` on my terminal but I get the notification `This command requires Expo CLI` with an option to install it globally. If I do this, I immediately get the same message with the same option to install Expo CLI even though it has just been installed. Is there a way to do something about it or work arround this issue?

My terminal looks like this now:

```
user@user-MacBook-Pro Project %  npm start              

> start
> expo start

This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]? y
Installing the package 'expo-cli'...
Expo CLI installed. You can run `expo --help` for instructions.
This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]? y
Installing the package 'expo-cli'...
Expo CLI installed. You can run `expo --help` for instructions.
This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]? y
Installing the package 'expo-cli'...
Expo CLI installed. You can run `expo --help` for instructions.
This command requires Expo CLI.
Do you want to install it globally [Y/n]?
```

I would appreciate any advice, thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of installing Expo CLI via `npm start`, try to install Expo CLI separately first, then run `npm start`.

If the issue persists, try to run `expo start` directly instead of `npm start`, and see what it gives.